# error left padding a string with spaces

Tags: padding

I'm trying to pad a parameter with spaces such that it's always `10` characters long. Sometimes the data contains `7` characters other times `8`. I found something that works when the data are all numbers but gives an

```
Error converting data type `varchar` to float
```

whenever there is a letter. The data type is `Char(10)` and so is my parameter.

```
SELECT *
fROM EC21DATA.CSTMST
WHERE CSTNUM  = REPLACE(STR(@CustomerSeqNo,10),' ',' ')
```

works for this → `RPT_TEST_PADDING '1353287'` 
does not work for this → `RPT_TEST_PADDING 'U122603'`

Any ideas?

Comment: "'Error converting data type varchar to float' error whenever there is a letter" -- It happens.  Your data needs to be consistent with floating point number format  if you expect it to convert properly.

Comment: I tried converting the datatype but still get an error. We import this data into SQL from AS400 everynight, would converting it during import work better?

Answer (score -1):

Edit = equal replace by like and % used to match all the padded characters.

Could you do this?

```
SELECT *
fROM EC21DATA.CSTMST
WHERE CSTNUM  LIKE '%'+@CustomerSeqNo+'%'
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply.Yes but I dont want my users to have to pad the parameter and they woudl have to for that to work.